# How to make fix size of QDialog after using animation of resizing Dialog?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qdialog, qpropertyanimation

I'm using QtAnimation using setStartValue(Rect) and setEndValue(Rect) 
I want to make it of fixed size after animation.
How to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `QPropertyAnimation`, just connect it's `finished()` signal to some slot and set a fixed size for the dialog there.